# += Operator and the new Operator c#

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, method-group

Whats the differenct when using the += operator followed by a "new function" vs only the function name?

Eg

```
FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
```

or

```
FileSystemWatcher _fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(pathName);
_fileSystemWatcher.Created += _fileSystemWatcher_Created;
```

The later works, is there some rules about when to using what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dealing with events doing

```
watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
```

and

```
watcher.Created += OnChanged;
```

mean the exact same thing. Before [C# 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx) you could only do the first syntax, the shorter syntax was added later.

Comment: That syntax was adopted in C# 2.0 : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx